# SQLite запрос на внесение данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Есть 2 таблицы:

1. Таблица уже созданная в БД Customers:

```
    CREATE TABLE Customers (
    id             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    SoldTo         INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    SoldTo_name_en VARCHAR (100),
    SoldTo_name_ru VARCHAR (100) 
);
```

2. Временная таблица кодом Python вносится в БД из Excel-файла - tmp_customers (колонка index создается автоматически БД)

```
    CREATE TABLE tmp_customers (
    [index]        INTEGER,
    SoldTo         INTEGER,
    Soldto_name_en TEXT,
    Soldto_name_ru TEXT,
    ShipTo         INTEGER
    );
```

Суть в том, что из tmp_customers нужно отобрать 3 колонки и вставить в таблицу Customers.
Но при запуске запроса БД выдает ошибку, что в таблице Customers 4 колонки, а в отправляемых данных 3. Т.е. она не находит id, который по идее с AUTOINCREMENT должна заполняться автоматически и не обязательна для запроса INSERT.

Вот запрос на вставку и фильтрацию данных:

```
    INSERT INTO Customers
    SELECT tmp.SoldTo, tmp.Soldto_name_en, tmp.Soldto_name_ru
    FROM tmp_customers as tmp, Customers as c
    WHERE c.SoldTo <> tmp.SoldTo
```

Что не сделано неправильно?

Comment: Не указан список полей, в которые выполняется вставка. `INSERT INTO Customers (SoldTo, Soldto_name_en, Soldto_name_ru) SELECT ...`

Comment: @Akina Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ! Я так и думала, что решение на поверхности.

Comment: @Akina А вы не знаете, почему запрос перестает работать, как только в таблицу Customers пусто и нет ни одной строки (например, база только создана и все таблицы пустые). Таблица tmp создается нормально, а вот на запрос INSERT INTO ничего не происходит. Таблица Customers все также пустая?

Comment: Ну потому что логика в запросе такая. Если Customers пуста, то SELECT-часть вернёт пустой набор записей. Удалите Customers из FROM (зачем она там?), удалите вообще WHERE (дурное же условие), добавьте IGNORE (он заставит пропустить записи с существующим SoldTo).